# Visual Studio hides method and or class name when hiding text

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

When collapsing/hiding a method the name of the method is hidden with it. This is obviously counterintuitive since all I want to see is the method or class name. I tried looking though the settings but couldn't find anything that fixed it. Thanks for the help.

Class before being hidden

[image: 1]

Class after being hidden

[image: 2]

Comment: I agree. VSCode is still showing the method name and arguments when hiding the content, which is easier to read.